# Variable length array reshape for input to CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to ask about how I reshape an array with a different number of elements, For example, the size of the array is (1000,). I want to reshape it to be (1000, None,None,1) to be the input to CNN, I'm using keras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think 'None' can be accepted in any reshape function. Reshape functions usually require numeric size. But you can reshape 
'None' part to 1 to fit the model you are using.
For reshaping, 
considering x is the variable that needs to be reshaped,

- Using Numpy,
  x = np.reshape(x, (1000, 1, 1, 1))
- Using Tensorflow,
  x = tf.reshape(x, (1000, 1, 1, 1))

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I got this error 

" ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence "

Comment: Ok. It means that some of the elements of the array are missing. Make sure that array is complete before reshaping.